# Updating existing Watchkit app to WatchOS2

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

Yesterday I [saw this post](https://nozbe.com/blog/sorry/) and made me realize I have a problem.

I have created an WatchOS2 app after having an WatchOS1 app in the store. When I tried to run the app it [made me upgrade my bundle identifier name](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/10445) and now I have no idea if I will be able to submit my WatchOS2 app with a different bundle identifier. Does app store support two different bundle identifier for watch apps?

**EDIT**

With watchOS1 I had the following bundles:

```
|App               | my.app.com            |
|Watch             | my.app.com.watchkit   |    
|Watch Extension   | my.app.com.extension  |
```

And now, with watchOS2 I need to have the following:

```
|App               | my.app.com                       |
|Watch             | my.app.com.watchkit              |    
|Watch Extension   | my.app.com.watchkit.extension    | <- The difference
```

Can I submit with this difference?

Answer (score 2):

From the [watchOS 2 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/ConfiguretheXcodeProject.html):

> The base bundle identifier of all your watch targets must be identical to the bundle identifier of your iOS app. This behavior applies even when you have separate targets for both watchOS 1 and watchOS 2. The only differences between the bundle identifiers of any of the targets is the extensions that Xcode adds to identify the Watch app and WatchKit extension. iOS does not install Watch apps whose bundle identifier does not match the bundle identifier of its iOS app.

Also you can check the [Lister application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html) to see all the new stuff Apple has implemented for Watch including the backward compatibility with watchOS 1.

**Update for clarity:**
Here are bundle IDs for the watch app and watch extension respectively from the Lister app:

watchOS 1:

- com.example.apple-samplecode.Lister.watchkitapp
- com.example.apple-samplecode.Lister.watchkitextension

watchOS 2:

- com.example.apple-samplecode.Lister.watchkitapp
- com.example.apple-samplecode.Lister.watchkitapp.watchkitextension

The conclusion: As far as you see your bundle IDs naming is absolutely correct and feel free to submit your app.

Comment: I already have the same prefix. The problem is: I had an app called my.app.com, the watch had my.app.com.watchkit and the extension add my.app.com.watchextension. Now, with watchOS2 I need to have my.app.com, my.app.com.watchkit and my.app.com.watchkit.extension . How will this impact my submission?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitry! So what problem did those guys get -> https://nozbe.com/blog/sorry/ ?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida - Actually it's not that clear what really happened at nozbe. I guess they used the bundle ID without the prefix or something. I can't imagine how they even managed to submit an app with the wrong bundle ID to the store. As for me I also had a watchOS 1 app at the store and then adapted it to watchOS 2 and submitted with the new bundle ID without any problem, the only difference I didn't provide the backward compatibility with watchOS 1.

Comment: In addition the documentation and the Apple's Lister app provide a very compelling guide to action. I have nothing to add.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Probably I will test a submission to TestFlight but you already gave me a lot of confidence! Thank you very much!

Comment: I was thinking in accepting it after proving that it works on my case :D. As soon as I submit it I will accept it :).

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida, Is it possible to have 2 watchkit app with different bundle identifiers at the same time? I am having the same issue right now. Is my application going to be a new application or an update for the current one?